# Database date depending on SYSDATE with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select and return a number of rows depending on 'today's' date.

Something like...

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table
 WHERE 
 //some conditions AND

 my_DATE BETWEEN trunc (sysdate, 'mm')/*current month*/ AND SYSDATE
```

However I would like to return:

1. Only rows for the last two months (excluding this month) if today's date 'dd' is less than 15
2. Return rows for the last two months (including this month) if today's date is >= 15

I am thinking of a case. Something like

```
WHERE 
 (CASE 
    when trunc (sysdate, 'dd') < 15 THEN 
    TO_CHAR(my_DATE, 'MMYYY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR((add_months(sysdate,-3)) AND TO_CHAR((add_months(sysdate,-1))
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated as I get acquainted with this arena. Thank you

Comment: Did this code work?

Comment: No it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do all the computation on `sysdate`, to help the optimizer user indexes:

```
where datecol >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),
                            (case when extract(day from sysdate) < 15 then -2 else -1 end)
                           ) and
      datecol < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),
                            (case when extract(day from sysdate) < 15 then 0 else 1 end)
                           )
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment:

```
where datecol >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -2) and
      datecol < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),
                            (case when extract(day from sysdate) < 15 then 0 else 1 end)
                           )
```

Comment: Tried using this on @APC fiddle above at (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08ef4c83539581befbcaee309b4da9cb)

But the `>15` part is supposed to return JAN since it is part of the **previous two months**

Comment: @Sight . . . As I write this in late March, your question is describing two ranges:  JAN 1 - MAR 1 and FEB 1 - APR 1.  If you really want DEC 1 - MAR 1 and JAN 1 - APR 1, then just use `-3` and -2` in the first `case` expression.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon...
I actually wanted JAN - FEB (if date <15) and JAN - MARCH (if date >= 15)

I think what I need is `-2` and `-2` in the first case expression?

Comment: @Sight . . . I edited the answer.  I would figure that you would want the same number of months regardless of when in the month we are.  But you want to vary the number of months.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are not wholly clear, but I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from       mytable t
where (to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) < 15
       and t.dt >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'),-3)
       and t.dt  < trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
      )
or    (to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) >= 15
       and t.dt >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'),-2)
       and t.dt <= last_day(sysdate)
      )
```

I have put [a demo version of this code on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1774c42544a98368cd724bbc5ded244b) with an affordance for changing the date of *today* instead of using sysdate.

---

> the previous months should be FULL not previous months based on today's date.

To get full months, truncate the date using the `'mm'` mask, which returns the first of the month.

Comment: You can simplify it and use `EXTRACT( DAY FROM sysdate )` rather than chaining `TO_NUMBER` and `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: Thank you for the demo version on `db<>fiddle`.
The `>15` part doesn't bring JAN dates though.

Like you said may be my first message wasn't as clear but the previous months should be FULL not previous months based on today's date.

Comment: For future reference, **include sample data in your questions**. A handful of input dates and the expected output for different values of `today` would have made your question so much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If this represents sample data:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         1 20.12.2020
         2 07.01.2021
         3 15.02.2021
         4 25.02.2021
         5 10.03.2021
```

then see whether the following code makes sense. The whole `date '&&par_sysdate'` shuld be replaced by `sysdate` in *real life*; for testing purposes, I used a parameter as `sysdate` returns today's date.

First example: `par_sysdate = 10.03.2021` (day is less than 15):

```
SQL> select t.id, t.datum
  2  from test t
  3  where t.datum >=
  4    trunc(add_months(date '&&par_sysdate',
  5                     -case when to_number(to_char(date '&&par_sysdate', 'dd')) < 15 then 2
  6                           else 1
  7                      end
  8                    ), 'mm')
  9    and t.datum < case when to_number(to_char(date '&&par_sysdate', 'dd')) < 15 then
 10                            trunc(date '&&par_sysdate', 'mm')
 11                       else date '&&par_sysdate'
 12                  end;
Enter value for par_sysdate: 2021-03-10

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         2 07.01.2021
         3 15.02.2021
         4 25.02.2021
```

Second example: using today's date (`20.03.2021`) where day is greater than 15:

```
SQL> undefine par_sysdate
SQL> /
Enter value for par_sysdate: 2021-03-20

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         3 15.02.2021
         4 25.02.2021
         5 10.03.2021

SQL>
```

---

Or, as I said, using `sysdate`:

```
SQL> select t.id, t.datum
  2  from test t
  3  where t.datum >=
  4    trunc(add_months(sysdate,
  5                     -case when to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) < 15 then 2
  6                           else 1
  7                      end
  8                    ), 'mm')
  9    and t.datum < case when to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) < 15 then
 10                            trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
 11                       else sysdate
 12                  end;

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         3 15.02.2021
         4 25.02.2021
         5 10.03.2021

SQL>
```